# how to store user entered data from android application to server database in excel format?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android app, in which user should fill some parameters to store them to server database, i just want to store that parameters( data ) in Excel sheets instead of MySql database

Comment: So, you have to write a program at server side which make Excel Sheets of retrieving data from android application.

Comment: Welcom to SO, Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I do software consulting for $150/hr.